# mySQL How can I group dates from a transactions table into years when all I have is the end period and year duration?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a typical transactions table that shows ledger data by date. The data covers a period of about 6 years.     I have another table that simply includes an "endDate" and "Years".     I'm trying to find a way of grouping my transaction dates by a year number in the format -1, -2, -3 etc based on the endDate.

The endDate for example is "30/09/2016".  So any transaction falling between 01/10/2015 and 30/09/2016 would be -1, 01/10/2014 and 30/09/2015 would be -2 and so on.

I've tried using TIMESTAMPDIFF(year, endDate , transactiondate) but that is based on the year only and doesn't take into account that the year starts 1st October

I've attached an image of the expected outcome.  Any ideas would be much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Provide some sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts (screenshots are not useful) and desired output for this data woth explanations. Also specify **precise** MySQL version.

Comment: *but that is based on the year only and doesn't take into account that the year starts 1st October* Add 2 months (or substract 10 months), then extract the year. *I've tried using TIMESTAMPDIFF* - this is bad, the query will be slow. One of two dates must stay unchanged (the best way - a column from the table with more huge data).

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the one shown below to get the desired output

- Use Case-when in SQL statement for the `transactiondate`, `EndDate` fields to decide appropriately
- use date_diff if that works
  eg: `SELECT DATE_DIFF('30/6/2012', '30/09/2016', YEAR) AS year_diff`